# How do i create a json file with requests in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So i have a node.js + mongoose server with a CRUD, i made the routes, repositories and controllers, and i now needed to make it so every request made is saved on a json file, i'm trying to make it work on my indexroutes and it does create a json file with the request i'm making on postman, however while it creates de json file, postman returns me errors when i make the request, i wanted to know what i'm doing wrong.

Here's my IndexRoute code:

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

router.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
    next();
    data = [req.method, req.path, req.params, req.body]
    fs.writeFile("requests.json", JSON.stringify(data),
        () => {
            next();
        }
    ) 
});

module.exports = router;`
```

Comment: What's the error ? You are calling `next()` multiple times, you should probably remove the first call. It might be that you have no router after that so you might need to create another router to send a response or just send a response in this router.

Comment: JSON is a bad format for a log file that you incrementally add onto because JSON just doesn't work very well for appending.  You should probably just use what most log files use which is a comma delimited format that you can just append a new line onto the file at each request.

Comment: This code may also have concurrency issues as two requests could be be trying to call `fs.writeFile()` at about the same time so this approach is not recommended.  You will either need to pre-open a stream and keep the stream open and just have each incoming request write to the stream (which will organize the concurrency issues for you) or you will need a locking mechanism so the 2nd request doesn't initiate an `fs.writeFile()` until  the previous one is done.